# Absorbing nin-jutsu chakra (technique)

Tags: naruto

Here are the two scenarios,

1. In the movie `Naruto Shippuden the Movie: The Will of Fire` a ninja by name `Hiruko` while fighting with Naruto-san tries to absorb wind style `Rasen-Shuriken`. But he fails and exclaims that he can not absorb the technique.
2. In `Naruto Shippuden` anime series (I don't know exact episode number), when Naruto-san fights with `Pain`, one of the Pain successfully absorbs the `Rasen-Shuriken`.

Once the absorption is failed (in case of Hiruko), but other time its possible (in case of Pain).

Can anyone please explain how is this possible and reasons behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chakra absorbing technique used by [Hiruko](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hiruko_(missing-nin)) is [Dark Release: Inhaling Maw](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Release:_Inhaling_Maw). 
While in the case of Pain, or [Preta path corpse](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Preta_Path) to be precise, the technique is [Blocking Technique Absorption Seal](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Blocking_Technique_Absorption_Seal).
These two techniques seem to be no different right? No, it has a major difference.

> **Hiruko's** Dark Release: Inhaling Maw
>
> > Classification: [Kekkei Genkai](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kekkei_Genkai), [Ninjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ninjutsu), [Chakra Absorption Techniques](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra_Absorption_Techniques)
> > Usage: *Extract the physical and spiritual energy of another ninja, even from a considerable distance. He is able to completely remove the victim's chakra, potentially causing death.*

> **Preta path corpse's** Blocking Technique Absorption Seal
>
> > Classification: [Kekkei Genkai](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kekkei_Genkai), [Ninjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ninjutsu), [Dōjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Dojutsu), [Fūinjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Fuinjutsu), [Chakra Absorption Techniques](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra_Absorption_Techniques)
> > Usage: *A highly advanced sealing technique that is capable of absorbing any chakra, regardless of any shape or nature transformation. As a result, this technique can absorb any ninjutsu based technique, rendering it ineffective on the user.*

As I mentioned just now, there's a major difference, that is the classification. Note that Preta's path corpse's technique is classified as one of the *Dōjutsu* and *Fūinjutsu*. 
*Dōjutsu*, which possesses a number of passive abilities that normal *Ninjutsu* don't. Moreover, *Fūinjutsu* is also part of the classification. Recall what is *Fūinjutsu* -- *Fūinjutsu* are a type of jutsu that seals objects, living beings, chakra, along with a wide variety of other things within another object. Ultimately, Hiruko's Ninjutsu absorption technique is just an absorption ninjutsu. With any *Ninjutsu* that possesses larger amount of chakra than his absorption technique, he will end up being killed. However, Preta path corpse's Ninjutsu Absorption Sealing technique is stronger than Hiruko's one. Do you remember that Jiraiya sealed Itachi's *Dōjutsu*, [Amaterasu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Amaterasu) with his [Fire Sealing Method](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Sealing_Method)(A kind of *Fūinjutsu*)? Even the highest level of fire release that cannot be extinguished with water or any other normal methods could be sealed, not to mention it's absorbed by Hiruko's absorption technique. That's the power of *Fūinjutsu*.
[Source and info are taken from [*Narutopedia*](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Narutopedia). A wiki filled with SPOILERS about Naruto series :)]